# Custom Class in ASP.NET service is not accepted in my consuming client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll, client

I'm trying to create a simple ASP.NET webservice with an even simpler consuming client (console application) to test the passing of public classes from a .dll I made earlier.

For some reason it will not compile and returns this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'BDMTSShipLibrary.ShipBaseClass' to
>   'BdmtsServiceTester.localhost.ShipBaseClass'

The BdmtsPing-method works perfectly, but as soon as I try passing custom class parameters it dies.

The code for the service:

```
public class BdmtsService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string BdmtsPing(int i)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int p = 0; p <= i; p++)
            output += "Server is alive!\n";
        return string.Format(output + "Done!");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string PassTheShip(ShipBaseClass ship)
    {
        return ship.BaseShipToString();
    }
}
```

My client:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client is live...");

            localhost.BdmtsService myService = new localhost.BdmtsService();
            Console.WriteLine(myService.BdmtsPing(5));
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            ShipBaseClass myShip = new ShipBaseClass();
            Console.WriteLine(myService.PassTheShip(myShip););

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

The ShipBaseClass is defined in a .dll, which is referenced by "using" in both the .asmx of the service and the .cs of the client.

It seems to me, that the compiler doesn't consider all ShipBaseClasses to be equal, but what is my problem?

Comment: You probably have ShipBaseClass class in both BDMTSShipLibrary and in your web service project, you have to have one or use complete namespace to clarify this to compiler.

Comment: It seems like that could be the issue... Now I just need to figure out how to write it completely enough for the compiler...

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to simply cast it into a localhost.ShipBaseClass - since they're in fact the same?